# getting keyboard back from tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a graphical app, and at the start of the run I'd like to ask the user a single configuration question. The graphical framework (Panda3D) has ugly default dialog boxes, so I'd like to use something like tkInter to provide a modal dialog. I tried this:

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox

root = Tkinter.Tk()
# hide the root window
root.withdraw()

config.PLAY_MUSIC = tkMessageBox.askyesno( "My App", 
       "Would you like this app to play music from your iTunes collection?" )

root.destroy()
```

This does what I want it to, but it appears to route all further keyboard events to tkInter rather than my Panda3D app. I don't need to do anything further with tk after this dialog.

I can put the tk dialog into a separate app that chains onto mine, I suppose, but I'm wondering if there's a way to kill tk and get the keyboard back without exiting my app entirely.

Update: Tried root.quit(), which does seem to get the keyboard back, but I get a "Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate" crash on exit from my program, which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

**grab_release(self)**
Which does: *Release grab for this widget if currently set.*

Where *"A grab directs all events to this and descendant
widgets in the application."*

as in:

```
root.grab_release()
```

Hope you haven't tried this one.